# Errno::ECONNREFUSED in UsersController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

My application is up so then I proceeded to register. After I input my information I receive an error page saying:

Errno::ECONNREFUSED in UsersController#create

```
Connection refused - {:data=>"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><add><doc><field name=\"id\">User 1</field><field name=\"type\">User</field><field name=\"type\">ActiveRecord::Base</field><field name=\"class_name\">User</field><field name=\"username_text\">mikeadeleke</field><field name=\"bio_text\">Founder of Edopter</field></doc></add>", :headers=>{"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}, :method=>:post, :params=>{:wt=>:ruby}, :query=>"wt=ruby", :path=>"update", :uri=>#<URI::HTTP:0x007fb6c3c911d0 URL:http://localhost:8982/solr/update?wt=ruby>, :open_timeout=>nil, :read_timeout=>nil, :retry_503=>nil, :retry_after_limit=>nil}
```

The message:

```
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:14:in `create'
```

So here is my code that is causing the hold up. I see no issues and ran it through the roodi validator.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :get_user, except: [:new, :create]

    def get_user
        @user = User.find_by_username(params[:user_name])
    end

    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user])
        if @user.save
            sign_in @user
            flash[:success] = "Woohoo! Thanks for creating an account. Feel free to edit your profile or look around elsewhere!"
            redirect_to(user_url(@user.username))
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def show
        @resources_upvoted = []
        @user.upvotes.where(upvotable_type: "Resource").each do |upvote|
            @resources_upvoted << upvote.upvotable
        end
        @crafts_interested = []
        @resources_upvoted.each do |resource|
            craft = resource.craft
            if !@crafts_interested.include?(craft)
                @crafts_interested << craft
            end
        end
    end

    def edit
        if @user != current_user
            redirect_to user_url(@user.username)
        end
    end

    def update
        @user.email = params[:email]
        @user.bio = params[:bio]
        @user.save

        redirect_to edit_user_url(params[:user_name])
    end

    def destroy
        @user.destroy

        redirect_to home_url
    end
end
```

Comment: Looks like the problem is with your database connection. Verify that the info in `database.yml` is correct.

Comment: This is my code: 

development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/<%= Rails.env %>.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/<%= Rails.env %>.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/<%= Rails.env %>.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

Answer (score 9):

Your db connection is fine, in fact, you have answer in your error message ;)

If you will look at it you will find that code:

```
URL:http://localhost:8982/solr/update?wt=ruby>
```

which means you need to start your solr server. You may start it with simple `RAILS_ENV=your_env rake sunspot:solr:run`. Consider also adding some `begin... rescue` block around `@user.save` for outputting some message rather than letting whole app crash.

If you're interested why you get that error without an explicit call to solr - solr adds callback to `save` method, so it indexes every new (or updated) record which means you won't have (theoretically) reindex from scratch after adding new data.

Comment: Thanks. So then do I keep that server running because then I won't be able to open my application. I also received questions about my database.yml:

# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/<%= Rails.env %>.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/<%= Rails.env %>.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/<%= Rails.env %>.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

Comment: You don't need to keep running solr, it will fail only when you will use it (i.e. perform search or update). Your app != solr, those are two different things. As I've written, your db(sqlite3) is fine, solr (or rather sunspot) is an another database used for searching.

Comment: You cannot rescue exceptions from Sunspot in your controller. You can, but Sunspots also spawns a new thread which raises the exception and crashes the app. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704241/how-do-i-capture-a-rsolr-sunspot-exception-raised-on-a-different-thread-from-a-m